# jsonB SQL Command

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I am trying to get all records where `name` and `surname` are not `null` using postgres jsonB this is what I have:

```
select * 
  from dbo.users_sessions 
  where (user_properties->>'name' && 'surname') is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

The `&&` operator is for arrays and tests for "overlapping" values. You can't apply that to strings or JSON keys.

You need to query both keys separately.

```
select * 
from dbo.users_sessions 
where user_properties ->> 'name' is not null 
  and user_properties ->> 'surname' is not null;
```

Another option is to check for the *existence* of those keys (which might be something different then checking for null values):

```
select * 
from dbo.users_sessions 
where user_properties ?& array['name', 'surname'];
```